# Conditionally setting a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, case-statement

I'm trying to do this:

- If the Day parameter is the current day, then set `@EndDate` to be yesterday instead
- If the Day parameter is in the future, set `@EndDate` to yesterday.

I've tried a few different approaches including two down below. I'm fairly new to programming so odds are I'm missing something fairly simple. Basically, I am trying to set `@EndDate` conditionally, depending on what `@Day` is set to be.

```
DECLARE @Day DATETIME

SET @Day = '09/2/17 12:50'  
SET @Day = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Day), 0)

DECLARE @Enddate DATETIME

SET @Enddate = CASE @Day  
                  WHEN @Day < GETDATE() THEN GETDATE() - 1
               END

--SET @Enddate = @Day  
--     WHERE @Day < GETDATE()  
--SET @Enddate = GETDATE()-1    
--     WHERE@Day >= GETDATE()
```

Thanks

Comment: So just set @EndDate to be yesterday, since both conditions do the same.  Did you mean to do that?

Comment: What about the time part? how do you what to handle it? day is today 11:00, now is 13:00 what time is yesterday? 11:00, 13:00 or 00:00 or 23:59?

Comment: @Agapwlesu No, because if someone was to set Day to be any day before yesterday, I want Enddate to be that day. So, if Day = 4/5/15 then Enddate should equal 4/5/15 also. I only want Enddate to equal yesterday if Day  is set to be the current day or a day in the future.

Comment: @Horaciux I already got rid of the time part when setting Day -

Comment: getdate()-1 is actual time, you don't care?

Comment: @Horaciux Oh, I see what you mean. Yeah, i need to get rid of time there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the two possible ways to write a case expression...

You can either use

```
CASE @day 
   WHEN GETDATE() THEN 'x' 
   WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE() THEN 'y' 
END
```

or then you can use:

```
CASE 
   WHEN @day = GETDATE() THEN 'x' 
   WHEN @day > GETDATE() THEN 'y' 
END
```

This is the correct way:

```
SET @Enddate = CASE 
                  WHEN @Day < GETDATE() 
                     THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
                     ELSE GETDATE()
               END
```

Answer (score 1):

For clarification, variable `@yesterday` added as `DATE` without time

```
Declare @Day datetime

Set @Day = '09/02/17 12:50'
SET @Day = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Day), 0)

Declare @Enddate Datetime

Declare @yesterday as date
SET @yesterday=dateadd(day,-1,getdate())

Set @Enddate = Case 
When @day<  @yesterday Then @day else @yesterday  End
```

Any values older than yesterday remains as is, other case sets yesterday

Comment: One should **NOT** use `GETDATE()-1` - that's the current date&time minus one ....... what!?!??!? Year? Month? Day? Minute? Hour? Second? Use a proper `DATEADD(....)` call instead to make it **crystal clear** what you're subtracting from the current date&time ...

Comment: It is casted as DATE as OP required, no time involved, see previous comments in original question. @marc_s do you still think it should be modified?

Comment: Yes - it's still unclear - and even if you cast it to a `DATE` later on - it's still not obvious what "1" you've subtracted..... I would recommend to always use the `DATEADD()` approach to make your intent crystal clear to everyone who needs to read your code later on

Comment: @Horaciux The other answer just ended up working better with what I was trying to do.